# how to apply jquery ui draggable more than one time to same element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I apply jquery ui draggable or resizable more than one time to same element? For example:

```
<div style="height: 50px; left: 216px; position: absolute; top: 64px; width: 444px; z-index: 1; class="test-12 ui-resizable ui-draggable" id="div-77">
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
   <div class="ui-rotatable-handle ui-draggable show"></div> 
</div>
```

I want to apply jquery draggable and resizable to this div (id=div-77) with these other divs

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Like most things in jQuery you can use a CSS selector to choose the elements you want.  This will make all `div`s resizable and draggable.

```
$('div')
    .resizable()
    .draggable();
```

If you just want the div with ```id="div-77" you can use.

```
$('#div-77')
    .draggable()
    .resizable();
```

Calling `draggable` or `resizable` on the same element multiple times has no ill effect.  jQuery UI internally is smart enough to know that it has already made the element `draggable` or `resizable` accordingly.

Comment: ok, thank you bro. how jquery kept records about those element.

Comment: The jQuery UI widget factory does it through jQuery's data method.  You can read more about the widget factory here - http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory and that data method's docs are here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/.

Comment: Did you need anything else?  If not and my answer was helpful to you would you mind selecting it?  Thanks.